# How to write test case for play pause stop functions of mobile using ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know a little about test driven development in ruby but I don't no the logic behind to write test cases for start pause stop functions in ruby. I know asking complete code is not a good behaviour. Can anyone give me a hint from which I can understand and start my research? Just I need the foundation about that...

Comment: What are these functions? Please explain where these "play pause stop" functions are, and what you expect them to do.

Answer (score 0):

From the little information you provide, we cannot really know how your program is structured, but typically, a spec like that would be like :

```
it "should pause when pause method is invoked" do
  mobile = Mobile.create(...)
  mobile.pause
  mobile.paused.should == 1
end
```

where paused is a model attribute indicating whether it's paused or not.